# Prove that median $AD$ is greater than $\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}$

Tags: inequality, triangles

Prove that

Median $AD>\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}$

My attempt i tried using am gm inequality but cant figure out the way...

Any help will be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: Show please, how exactly you tried to use AM-GM and I'll show my solution.

Comment: ' i tried using am gm inequality but cant figure out the way...'  cannot be justified as an attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying triangle inequality

$AD+CD>AC$, $\triangle ACD$

$AD+BD>AB$, $\triangle ABD$

$2AD+CD+BD>AC+AB$

$2AD+BC>AC+AB$

$2AD>AC+AB-BC$

Comment: It was very use i was thinking it was tough